# Update Mysql Table column using another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table column with below query.

```
UPDATE `prayer_times` SET `maghrib_jamat` =  `maghrib` + .05;
```

I have two column `maghrib_jamat` and `maghrib`. In `maghrib` values are like `18:42` which is a time value with `varchar` type. I would like to add 5 minutes with `maghrib` and insert that value into `maghrib_jamat` column. I am getting error `#1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '18:42'`.

How can I do the task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the time value as time and use `ADDTIME` function to add the required minutes to it as the following:

```
UPDATE prayer_times 
SET maghrib_jamat =  
  DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(CAST(maghrib AS TIME), '00:05:00'), '%H:%i')
```

The use of `DATE_FORMAT` is to remove the seconds part from the casted time.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/S_tG3mF6).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
declare @t datetime = getdate()
select @t , @t + '00:05' , dateadd(minute, 5, @t)
```

Code illustrate different ways of doing it :)

Comment: The OP has tagged `mysql` *not* `sql-server`

Comment: Thanks @johndk. Is it MySql SQL Query ?